# Stuck substring in vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net

In Example, i have string as the following:

[oledb]
; Everything after this line is an OLE DB initstring
`Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=123456;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=BMC;Data Source=`.

I would like sub string only password and User ID in vb 2005.

How to do that ?

The result that i need: `Password=123456 and User ID=sa` .

Comment: I would try using string.split with ";" as the token. Then you could access the index 1 and 3 of the returned array, and that'd be your result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it with old-school string parsing, then:

```
    Dim data As String = "[oledb] ; Everything after this line is an OLE DB initstring" & vbCrLf _
                         & "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=123456;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=BMC;Data Source="


    Dim password As String = ""
    Dim userID As String = ""

    Dim semiColonIndex As Integer

    Dim passIndex As Integer = data.IndexOf("Password=")
    If passIndex > 0 Then
        semiColonIndex = data.IndexOf(";", passIndex)
        If semiColonIndex > 0 Then
            password = data.Substring(passIndex + "Password=".Length, semiColonIndex - passIndex - "Password=".Length)
            Debug.Print(password)
        End If
    End If

    Dim userIndex As Integer = data.IndexOf("User ID=")
    If userIndex > 0 Then
        semiColonIndex = data.IndexOf(";", userIndex)
        If semiColonIndex > 0 Then
            userID = data.Substring(userIndex + "User ID=".Length, semiColonIndex - userIndex - "User ID=".Length)
            Debug.Print(userID)
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: Kind of sad that this got accepted -- now someone would have to maintain this old school solution instead of built-in parsing support.

Answer (score 0):

As this is a connection string, you should be able to use `OleDbConnectionStringBuilder` to parse it.

An example would be something like:

```
Dim builder As New OleDbConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString)
' builder("User ID") contains User ID
' builder("Password") contains Password
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below, It will help you...

for SQL Connection using `SQLClient` then try like below...

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

    Dim constring As String
    constring = "Password=123456;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=BMC;Data Source="
    Dim builder As New SqlConnectionStringBuilder(constring)
    Console.WriteLine("Username : " + builder.UserID)
    Console.WriteLine("Password : " + builder.Password)
```

By using `OLEDB Provider` then try like below...

```
 Imports System.Data.OleDb 

    Dim oledbbuilder As New OleDbConnectionStringBuilder("Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=123456;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=BMC;Data Source=")
    Console.WriteLine("Username : " + oledbbuilder("User ID").ToString)
    Console.WriteLine("Password : " + oledbbuilder("Password").ToString)
```

Comment: I think it may be better to cast instead of calling `ToString` -- I see people who are not used to casting doing `Int32.Parse(x.ToString)` to convert `Object` to `Integer`.